Growth Order of the Jacobi function
Show that if $\tau$ is fixed with $\operatorname{Im}(\tau)>0$, then the Jacobi theta function
$$
\Theta(z \mid \tau)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\pi i n^2 \tau} e^{2 \pi i n z}
$$
is of order 2 as a function of $z$. Further properties of $\Theta$ will be studied in Chapter 10 .
[Hint: $-n^2 t+2 n|z| \leq-n^2 t / 2$ when $t>0$ and $n \geq 4|z| / t$.]
My solution is as follows: We have
\begin{align}
    |\Theta(z \mid \tau)| &= \left|\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\pi i n^2 \tau} e^{2 \pi i n z}\right|\\
    &\leq\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} |e^{\pi i n^2 \tau} ||e^{2 \pi i n z}|\\
    &\leq \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\pi \operatorname{Im}(\tau) n^2 } e^{2\pi n |z|}\\
&= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\pi(- \operatorname{Im}(\tau) n^2 + 2 n |z|)}
\end{align}
Using the inequality in the hint, we can set $t =  \operatorname{Im}(\tau)$ since by assumption $\operatorname{Im}(\tau) > 0$. Therefore, when $n \geq 4|z|/\operatorname{Im}(\tau)$,
\begin{align}
     |\Theta(z \mid \tau)|  &\leq \sum_{|n| \leq 4|z|/\operatorname{Im}(\tau)}e^{-\pi \operatorname{Im}(\tau) n^2 } e^{2\pi n |z|} + \sum_{|n| \geq 4|z|/\operatorname{Im}(\tau)} e^{-\pi \operatorname{Im}(\tau) n^2/2} \\
     &\leq \sum_{|n| \leq 4|z|/\operatorname{Im}(\tau)}e^{-\pi \operatorname{Im}(\tau) n^2 } e^{2\pi n |z|} + \underbrace{\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty e^{-\pi \operatorname{Im}(\tau) n^2/2}}_{< \infty} \\
     &\leq |z|e^{A|z|^2}
\end{align}
This last term has an extra $|z|$ in it which I'm not sure how to get rid of it.
Note: I'm aware there is a stack exchange post fo this question already, but I don't see how they addressed my concern above so I made a new post.
On the growth of the Jacobi theta function

In fact any polynomial before the exponential term would not affect the growth order, since by definition the order of growth of a function is the infimum over all "bounds".

In that case wouldn't we have to show that any $\rho < 2$ we don't have $|f(z)| \leq Ae^{B|z|^\rho}$?

You are right. To get this, you can use repeatedly Proposition 1.1 (iii) of Chapter 10 from Stein & Shakarchi's Complex Analysis, which is about the quasi-periodicity of $\Theta$, to see that $\Theta(x+m\tau\mid\tau)=e^{-2\pi imx-\pi im^2\tau}\Theta(x\mid\tau)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $m\in\mathbb{N}$. Then take $x=0$ to get $\left|\Theta(m\tau\mid\tau)\right|=e^{\pi m^2\operatorname{Im}(\tau)}\left|\Theta(0\mid\tau)\right|=Ae^{B|m\tau|^2}$. Hence the order is at least $2$.

Besides what I noted in the comment above, there is another way that gives your desired result directly.
You are now dealing with the series
$$\sum_{|n|\leq4|z|/\operatorname{Im}(\tau)}e^{-\pi\operatorname{Im}(\tau)n^2}e^{2\pi n|z|}.$$
When $|n|\leq4|z|/\operatorname{Im}(\tau)$ one has $2\pi n|z|\leq8\pi|z|^2/\operatorname{Im}(\tau)$, and with the familiar inequality $e^{-x}\leq\frac{1}{x+1}$ we get
\begin{align*}
\sum_{|n|\leq4|z|/\operatorname{Im}(\tau)}e^{-\pi\operatorname{Im}(\tau)n^2}e^{2\pi n|z|}&\leq e^{8\pi|z|^2/\operatorname{Im}(\tau)}\sum_{|n|\leq4|z|/\operatorname{Im}(\tau)}\frac{1}{\pi n^2\operatorname{Im}(\tau)+1}\\
&\leq Ce^{8\pi|z|^2/\operatorname{Im}(\tau)}.
\end{align*}
